# Did you have a holiday recently? vs Have you had a holiday recently?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

1. Could you explain it's possible to use the Past Simple with key word "recently" or must always be the Present Perfect?
2. I have two sentences. Is the first sentence wrong? If I use the Past Simple I can write "Did you have a holiday last time?", but not "Did you have a holiday recently?", is it?

> Did you have a holiday recently?

vs

> Have you had a holiday recently?

Thanks.

Comment: "Have you *been on* holiday recently?" is idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my (British) English, both are pefectly good, and usable in exactly the same situations. The difference is in how the speaker is choosing to structure the temporal relationships: in the first they are choosing to treat "having a holiday" as an event complete in the past. In the second they are choosing to treat "having a holiday" as occupying a portion of the time stretching from whatever the limits of "recently" might be, up to the present.

I think this is the same for other Englishes, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: For example, you meet your colleague at work and you want to know when he was on holiday. Which variant will you choose to ask the question? Thanks.

Comment: Either. _Have you had_ is probably more common, especially if it is still the holiday season. But _Did you have_ is always possible.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Colin's answer I would add:

**Did you do/have something.....** is more likely in a follow-up question
or as part of a continuing conversation.

A: >I spotted a bear near the top of the mountain last week.
B: >Did you really climb the mountain?
A: >No, I took the cable car!

Or, it is used in posing a question about a particular event:

> Did you see the fireworks display last night?
> Did you hear the result of the big match?
> Did you know that he has been fired?

**Have you....** is a more likely to be a neutral question?

> Have you ever travelled overseas?
> Have you had a holiday in Greece?
> Have you seen the latest movie?

But, as Colin says, they are frequently interchangeable.